# Yahoo login integration in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetopenauth, yahoo

Can some provide me an example for integrating yahoo login authentication in asp.net c# Website.

I have searched google but all of them are for facebook, gmail and twitter. I dont know how to implement it for yahoo

Comment: http://www.beabigrockstar.com/guides/aspnet-oauth/aspnet-mvc-yahoo-login

Comment: Thank you for your response but can it be done without using mvc

Comment: have u check this? http://michiel.vanotegem.nl/2013/09/asp-net-openidoauth-login-with-asp-net-4-5-part-6/

Comment: Checked it just now. It is also using mvc.

Comment: no it had webform, in WebForms go to the RegisterOpenAuth method and add the following line of code:
OpenAuth.AuthenticationClients.Add("Yahoo!", () => new DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.Clients.YahooOpenIdClient());